# Custom visualforce login page to community

Tags: visualforce, community, login

I know it's been asked all over but I get nowhere applying the suggestions.
I have a community build with custom template. At the moment I want to just use the **public site** and public pages. Launch of the community is not on the roadmap.
I thought I will additionally **block the default login page** to stop more salesforce aware folks from venturing where they should not. I'm not convinced business will get a custom domain sorted in time and I want to prevent people from guessing url and seeing the standard salesforce login pages.
External user registration is disabled but people can still hang

I created a  custom VF page, because I can and because the doc says it should work, and I could re-use the generic page for some standard pages on the site. I configured the login in
[community workspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_custom_login_page_login.htm) however when I go to the url https://mycompany.force.com/myCommunity/s/login/ 
I see the login page from **experience builder.** Is there something I'm doing  wrong?
Worst case I can override the lightning page but I would like to understand what is wrong.
Custom home page works but this is also configured in the site settings.

Comment: Is there a strong reason to (try to) use Visualforce here, instead of simply tailoring your standard Lightning Community login page and/or ensuring self-registration is disabled? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/329231/edit) your question to clarify why you are concerned to stop "more salesforce aware folks from venturing where they should not"? I'm interested to understand your motivation. Also, is there a specific reason you kept the "/s/" in the URL?

Comment: Since you found a duplicate I suggest the conversation move there and we close this one...

Comment: BTW given that Visualforce is two generations ago, I would suggest always trying to avoid using it where possible.

Comment: Thanks for re-pasting my link Phil.